# Converge of Integral of Bounded Differentiable Function

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I am told that $h$ is a bounded differentiable function on $[0,\infty)$ with $h(0)=0$. I wish to show that
$$\int_0^\infty{\left|h\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)\right|\,dx} < \infty~.$$

I know that, because $h$ is differentiable at $0$, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^+}{\dfrac{h(x)}{x}} = h^\prime(0)$. I'm assuming this is leading me to use dominated convergence, but am not sure how to proceed.